# How to test significant improvement of LRM model

Tags: r, predictive, model-comparison

Using the `rms package` of Frank Harrell I constructed a predictive model using the `lrm function`.

I want to compare if this model has a significant better predictive value on a binomial event in comparison with another (lrm-) model.

I used different functions like `anova(model1, model2)` or the `pR2 function` of the `pscl library` to compare the pseudo R^2, but they all don't work with the lrm based model.

What can I do best to see if my new model is significant beter than the earlier model?

Update: Here is a example (where I want to predict the chance on bone metastasis) to check if size or stage (in addition to other variabele) gives the best model:

```
library(rms)
getHdata(prostate)

ddd <- datadist(prostate)
options( datadist = "ddd" )

mod1 = lrm(as.factor(bm) ~ age + sz + rx, data=prostate, x=TRUE, y=TRUE)

mod2 = lrm(as.factor(bm) ~ age + stage + rx, data=prostate, x=TRUE, y=TRUE)
```

Comment: You don't give an example to try, but broom::glance(model1) will give the log Likelihood and you can compare log likelihoods to see if there is an improvement.

Comment: I was wrong, broom::glance(model1) does not work.

Comment: I have added an example

Comment: For a predictive model, I'd strongly recommend fitting to a training set and using a test set to evaluate performance. Otherwise you will probably overfit.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I certainly intend to do this. The code I gave was just a minimal working example.

Answer (score 0):

It seems fundamentally the question is about comparing two **non-nested** models.

If you fit your models using the glm function you can use the -vuong- function in -pscl- package.

Answer (score 0):

To test the fit of 2 nested models, you can use the lrtest function from the "rms" package.

lrtest(mod1,mod2)

Comment: note that the example by the OP does not show nested models ...